# Two Sum problem from leetcode . TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.

```
#Two Sum Function
def twosum(nums,target,size):
    for i in nums(0,size):
        if(nums[i]+nums[i+1] == target):
            print("Output:",i,i+1)
#Driver Code
nums = []
n=int(input("Enter the size of array:"))
size=n-1
for _ in range(n):
    nums.append(input("Enter the array element: \t"))

print("Entered array:\t",nums)

target=int(input("Enter the sum to be find:"))
twosum(nums,target,size)
```

```
Output 

Enter the size of array:4
Enter the array element:        1
Enter the array element:        2
Enter the array element:        3
Enter the array element:        4
Entered array:   ['1', '2', '3', '4']
Enter the sum to be find:5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DSA With Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 16, in <module>
    twosum(nums,target,size)
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DSA With Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in twosum
    for i in nums(0,size):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions ???

Tried but could not figured out what's wrong in it.

Comment: `for i in range(len(nums)):`?

Answer (score 1):

The comment already solves OP's problem, but I'll go a little more in-depth for those who face this issue on a similar problem.

Python, being a programming language with dynamic typing, has very little introspection on what the type of a variable is at runtime. This means if you make a `class` with a `quack()` method and then try to call `fly()`, the program will run despite the method call being invalid. It doesn't crash until it tries to actually call the nonexistent `fly()` method.

This is, in a sense, what is happening here. Under the hood, a lot of functionality you see in Python is implemented using magic, or "dunder" ("double-underscore") methods like `__get__`. For example, if you want to make a `class` called `Number` which uses the `+` operator, you have to implement the `__add__` method.

Functions, like everything else in Python, are objects (first-class objects, actually. You can really treat them as variables), and in order for a function named `foo` to be called as `foo("hi")`, it needs to have the `__call__` method implemented. So, `foo("hi")` is really `foo.__call__("hi")`.

So how, pray tell, does this error come into play?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DSA With Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 16, in <module>
    twosum(nums,target,size)
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DSA With Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in twosum
    for i in nums(0,size):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Looking at the top of the traceback ("debug output"), we see the problem occurs at:

```py
twosum(nums,target,size)
```

Starting at the top, going down, we reach closer and closer to the actual crash. This makes sense, as the first line of the `twosum` function you defined is

```py
for i in nums(0,size):
```

This leads us to the final piece of the puzzle:

```py
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The `TypeError` thrown here is reminiscent of what I said earlier: Python will assume your instance object has the `quack()` method even if it doesn't. In the case of a nonexistent instance method like `quack()`, Python will throw an `AttributeError` your way, but when it's a nonexistent dunder method, you usually get `TypeError`.

In this case, `'list' object is not callable` means you tried to take a `list`, say, `nums`, and execute `nums(0,size)`, which translates to, `nums.__call__(0,size)`, causing the error.

It seems there was a mix-up between choosing to iterate over the elements in `nums` vs iterating over indexes using `range(0, size)`.

To solely fix the issue posed in the question, you would need `range(len(nums))` or `range(0, size)`, the former being preferred because accessing the `len` (size) of a `list` is [image].

That being said, there are several other problems with the rest of the Two Sum code (left as an exercise to the reader).